# How to use "If so" properly

Tags: grammar

Is this correct to use "If so" in the following way?

> I just want to make sure if I have completed the process of accepting the scholarship; If so, would you please provide me an official letter about it.

Best

Comment: Yes, but you don't capitalize the first letter of the first word after a semicolon.  You'd either write, "...scholarship; if so, would you..." or write, "...scholarship.  If so, would you..."  I'm not putting this as an answer because this question will likely get deleted soon.  This is not a proofreading site, and there is an English Language Learner's site for asking questions like this (https://ell.stackexchange.com/).  You should direct future questions like this one there.

Comment: You have been offered a scholarship, and accepted it. If you are worried that your acceptance was not received, I would write: "Will you please confirm that I have a place on the XXX course as a result my scholarship award?"

Comment: "if I have completed" should be "that I have completed" or simply "I have completed"

Answer (score 2):

the idiom and examples of usage may help:  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/if+so)

**if so**

> if that is [the case]; if that is so.
>
> 'She might be late. If so, we will eat without her.' 'She is supposed to
>   be all right. If so, we have nothing to worry about.'

Your sentence without too much alteration wcould be:

> " I just want to make sure I have completed the process of
>   accepting the scholarship; if so, would you please provide me an
>   official letter about it."